# Newbie: Can't install magento 2.3.3 with nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: magento2.3.3

I'm relatively new with Magento, but I have already wasted many hours just to install Magento2 with nginx on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a cloud, AWS, Gcloud etc... In the end it doesn't work...

[image]

The result that I get is a page: Autoload error
Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.

I did install composer, then I got some missing symfony/mime ^4.3, then everything got f-ed up.

What am I doing wrong? Do you know of any good tutorial on how to Install latest magento with nginx on ubuntu, I tried them all on the first and second page of google and only 2 videos on youtube. None of them worked for me.

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not able to install composer on the server, you can use composer.phar file directly :

Step 1 : 
Download [composer.phar](https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/blob/master/web/download/1.0.0-alpha11/composer.phar) file , open url and click on donwload

Step 2 : put that on magento root, and run

```
php composer.phar install
```